# classe especificada mas jQuery salta elemento

Tags: jquery

Tenho esse **HTML**

```
<div class="slider">

 <div class="slide ativa">
   <img class="fade" src="http://funerariasaopedro.net.br/novo/_img/_banner/_site/bg_1.jpg" />
   <span>Este é 1</span>
 </div>

 <div class="slide">
   <img class="fade" src="http://funerariasaopedro.net.br/novo/_img/_banner/_site/bg_2.jpg" />
   <span>Este é 2</span>
 </div>

 <nav>
  <button class="anterior">Anterior</button>
  <button class="proximo">Próximo</button>
 </nav>

</div>
```

E esse jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  function startslider() {  

    ativa = $("div.slider div.ativa")

    if (!$(ativa).next().length) {
      ativa = blocos[0]
    }

     $(ativa)
        .removeClass("ativa")
        .next()
        .addClass("ativa")

     setTimeout(startslider, 5000)
  }

  setTimeout(startslider, 5000)

})
```

A ideia aqui é percorrer ***APENAS*** as `divs` cuja classe é `.slide`.
Não pode chegar a correr na tag **NAV**.

Mas parece que o **jQuery** está setando o objeto `NAV` também para a **classe** `.slide`.

Como corrigir isso?
A impressão que tenho é a de que

$(ativa).next().length

Sempre será verdadeira pois não há nenhuma comparação com `.slide` para saber o de tem `div.slide`

Comment: Não deixe de finalizar ou dar um feedback nas suas perguntas. Isso é importante pra comunidade.

Comment: A maioria das suas perguntas estão sem marcações com uma resposta certa. Isso não é nada interessante pra comunidade. Isso quer dizer que vc faz perguntas, obtém respostas e não finaliza ou marca nenhuma como correta, ou não procura solucionar... isso foge do propósito do site. Reveja as suas perguntas e procure solucioná-las.

Comment: Complementando, abandonar perguntas é ruim tanto pra comunidade quanto pra quem tentou responder. Reveja isso.

Comment: Esta pergunta está sendo debatida no meta: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7041/132

Comment: concordo contigo. Desculpe. erro meu. já corrigi. Escolhi uma resposta que, para mim, foi de mais fácil compreensão. Mas obrigado pela orientação. Não vai se repetir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É isso que está acontecendo mesmo. Este `.next()` abaixo está pegando o próximo elemento após o `.ativa`, no caso, o `nav`:

```
$(ativa)
.removeClass("ativa")
.next()
.addClass("ativa")
```

O que precisa fazer é verificar se o `.next` no `if` é uma `div.slide`:

```
if (!$(ativa).next("div.slide").length) {
```

Mas é preciso também fazer um tratamento diferente, por isso é necessário inserir um `else` para retornar a classe `.ativa` para o primeiro elemento com `.first()`.

Veja como ficaria:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {

   function startslider() {  
   
      ativa = $("div.slider div.ativa")
   
      if (!$(ativa).next("div.slide").length) {
         // remove a classe do último
         $(ativa)
         .removeClass("ativa")
   
         // adiciona a classe no primeiro
         $("div.slider div.slide")
         .first()
         .addClass("ativa")
      }else{
         $(ativa)
         .removeClass("ativa")
         .next()
         .addClass("ativa")
      }
   
      setTimeout(startslider, 5000)
   }
   
   setTimeout(startslider, 5000)

})
```

```css
div.ativa{
   display: block;
}

.slide{
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">

 <div class="slide ativa">
   <img class="fade" src="http://funerariasaopedro.net.br/novo/_img/_banner/_site/bg_1.jpg" />
   <span>Este é 1</span>
 </div>

 <div class="slide">
   <img class="fade" src="http://funerariasaopedro.net.br/novo/_img/_banner/_site/bg_2.jpg" />
   <span>Este é 2</span>
 </div>

 <nav>
  <button class="anterior">Anterior</button>
  <button class="proximo">Próximo</button>
 </nav>

</div>
```